# Websockets connection over a range of source ip addresses

Tags: python, websocket, parallel-processing, range, ip

I have developed a simple code with python websockets to extract all markets data from kucoin.com exchange.
About 1200 subscribe on channels with real-time frequency like below:

Thread1 -> Websockets.subscribe('/market/level2:BTC-USDT,ETC-USDT,...')

Thread2 -> Websockets.subscribe('/market/level2:ETH-USDT,ETH-BTC,...')

and so on...

My code is running on a virtual server with 4xCore-xeon + 4GB RAM + 10Gbps port + 8 IP addresses.
I know that python websockets connects to destination host with default system IP. but connection on a single source IP has data latency for this number of work! I think this is because of API restriction policies for each IP

```
import websocket, kucoin
from threading import Thread

...

def proc_websocket(symbols):
    def on_ping(wsapp, message):pass
    def on_pong(wsapp, message):pass
    def on_error(wsapp, message):print(message)
    def on_open(wsapp):
        wsapp.send(json.dumps({'type':'subscribe', 'topic':'/market/level2:' + ','.join(symbols), 'response':True}))
    def on_message(wsapp, message):
        func_do_some_works_on_data(message)
    kucoin.get_ws_endpoint()
    ws_endpoint_url = f"{wss_endpoint['instanceServers'][0]['endpoint']}?token={wss_endpoint['token']}"
    while True:
        wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp(ws_endpoint_url, on_message=on_message, on_open=on_open, on_error=on_error, on_ping=on_ping, on_pong=on_pong)
ping_interval=18, ping_timeout=10)
        wsapp.run_forever(ping_interval=15, ping_timeout=10)


symbols = kucoin.get_symbols_all()
Thread(target=proc_websocket, args=(symbols[:100],)).start()
Thread(target=proc_websocket, args=(symbols[100:200],)).start()
Thread(target=proc_websocket, args=(symbols[200:300],)).start()
```

I want to set Websockets library or any other similar library so that connect through multiple source IP addresses. in fact it must divide the work through all my existed IPs. i.e connect websocket1 with IP1, websocket2 with IP2, ...

Is there any way to do this work?

Comment: What you're looking for is domain names. When you search for website you usually don't only have one resolvable fixed IP. The site is resolved for multiple hosts through the domain name system (DNS), and the hosts will resolve an IP by requesting to translate the domain name in the DNS. Different DNS will allow you to choose how you assign IPs for matching servers with dns load balancing techniques, such as considering server load or basic round‑robin style assignment.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS